# what's happens with transition pages in iPhone

Tags: ionic-framework

### why i having a problem in the **iPhone** but android  work good

problem usually occurs between the pages in IOS

for example :

when go to other page usually go and back in the same time without click the back button .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the fix recommended by Ionic team:

https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

1. Place downloaded file into `www/js` folder.
2. Add script tag in index.html: `<script src="js/ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch.js"></script>`
3. Add new dependency in `app.js`: `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch'])`

More info about that bug: http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me hours !